# Bootstrap - make navbar link area match size of custom navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have custom bootstrap navbar. So I have been added 20px padding to the bottom and top of navbar, also I ve set navbar links to change background color on hover. Now Im facing problem with the padding Ive added before, when navbar link is hovered and background color which is changed on hover, do not match size of navbar, there is space around of it. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW6yJ.jpg) I want to make hovered area of navbar link same size as my custom navbar. If someone can help me with this. Here is [Bootply fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/RMaFu600SS) 
Thanks

```
HTML file
    <!-- Navbar start -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">brand</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                 <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        <!-- Navbar end -->
```

CSS file

```
#navbar{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#navbar .navbar-brand{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: coral;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#navbar li a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #484651;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}


#navbar li:hover a:hover{
  background-color: #303036;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can u make a fiddle or bootply with ur code?

Comment: Hello, Im updated my question now, and added  bootply example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this updated bootply : http://www.bootply.com/bIkOZWIkBB. Remove padding-top & padding-bottom from #navbar and add  `padding-top: 35px;` and `padding-bottom: 35px;` to #navbar li a, such as :

```
#navbar li a {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #484651;
    font-size: 12px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
```

And then add padding top & bottom for `<a>` tag with website name, such as:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
">My Website</a>
```